# When did Cyrus II release the captives of Babylon?

Tags: persia, judaism, ancient-babylon

The text below are bits I want to discuss that are taken from the Cyrus Cylinder — dated 539–530 BCE.

> "I am Cyrus, king of the universe, the great king, the powerful king, king of Babylon, king of Sumer and Akkad, king of the four quarters of the world … My vast army marched into Babylon in peace; I did not permit anyone to frighten the people of [Sumer] /and\ Akkad.  I sought the welfare of the city of Babylon and all its sacred centers. As for the citizens of Babylon, [x x x upon wh]om henote imposed a corvée which was not the gods' wish and not befitting them,  I relieved their weariness and freed them from their service. Marduk, the great lord, rejoiced over [my good] deeds… ] I returned the images of the gods, who had resided there, note to their places and I let them dwell in eternal abodes. I gathered all their inhabitants and returned to them their dwellings.
> [*BritishMuseum*](https://research.britishmuseum.org/research/collection_online/collection_object_details.aspx?objectId=327188&partId=1)

In between this, Cyrus mentions many kings coming before him and kissing his feet. Apart from that the text of the Cyrus Cylinder gives the impression that the act of allowing the captives to go back to their original homelands was quite soon into his reign. He came to the throne in October 539 BCE. The book of Ezra says this decree happened in his first year (Ez. 1:1) which would have been between March 538/537 BCE <sup>*</sup>.
If this is true the decree would've happened at least 5 months after ascending the throne. Would it be more probable that the decree happened a lot sooner in his reign as can be interpreted in the Cyrus Cylinder?

* Note: Babylonians dated the first year of a king's reign from Nisan the following year of when a king came to the throne. Since Ezra was born in Babylonian captivity it'll be logical to assume he used the same method to date a king's reign. Hence, the first year of Cyrus, according to Ezra, would've begun on Nisan 1 (mid March) 538 BCE. October 539 BCE, when Cyrus came to the throne, is 5 months earlier.

Comment: I take it you arrive at the time difference of 5 months because you assume that the first year counts from the first Nowruz celebration, which would have been in March 538, not literally the first 365 days of his reign. Why?

Comment: Also note that Ezra may not be a reliable historical source.

Comment: Babylonians dated the first year of a king's reign from Nisan the following year of when a king came to the throne. Since Ezra was born in Babylonian captivity it'll be logical to assume he used the same method to date a king's reign. Hence, the first year of Cyrus, according to Ezra, would've begun in Nisan 1 (mid March) 538 BCE. October 539 BCE, when Cyrus came to the throne, is 5 months earlier.

Comment: @Hello - please add that to the question.  Questions that contain all the information needed tend to get more answers and better answers than questions where people have to search through the comment string to find information.  The best possible question will result in the best possible answer.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Agree with Mark: Plz add this to the question. What would Ezra have called it then had Cyrus done this before March 538? "Before the first year of his reign"? "When he conquered Babylon"? "Before his first Nisan 1"?

Comment: Is "henote" actually "he" with a subscripted "_note_"?

Comment: @0range As reliable as Cyrus ;)

Comment: The text nowhere explicitly says, nor implicitly suggests, anything about any time span, either long or short, and certainly not with the draconic precision you are demanding.

Comment: Checking against the British Museum transcription/translation: the 'quoted' text seems different to what's found on the website?